# oracle 11g user exists but when try to drop it says user doesn't exist

Tags: oracle11g

Mine is Oracle 11g XE. I have installed Navicat 11 for an easy UI control. Its a software very handy for handling several database software including Oracle. In that software a user 'wahid' was created (along with a new table under that user) but from my php code when I try to insert data it shows an error saying that table does not exist. So I tried to drop the user 'wahid' from Navicat but it shows an error says "ORA-01922: CASCADE must be specified to drop 'wahid'".

In the next step I tried to drop it from Oracle command line. There it says 'wahid' does not exist. But the problem is it actually does. I even tried the **CASCADE** option but it didn't work.

the SQL command line screenshot link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwpwu.png

What should I do or where should I look? TIA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try enclosing the user with quotes:

```
DROP USER "wahid";
```

or

```
DROP USER "wahid" CASCADE;
```

Comment: A reference to the difference between [quoted and non-quoted identifiers](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359%5F01/server.111/b28286/sql%5Felements008.htm#i27570) might be helpful. It would also explain why the OP was unable to insert.

Comment: adding double quote worked!! but why?? what did i miss?

Comment: Without the double quotes Oracle's engine will treat the username as WAHID (uppercase).